# How do I get the Tsavo highway skull on halo 3?

Tags: halo-3

I was reading my halo 3 tip guide and it said the way to get the "tough luck" skull was to go to this platform by crouch jumping there. Well I did so but did not find it. What has happened what did I do wrong? If you could post a very helpful video that would help a lot 'cause I do better with visuals. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The skull is called Tough Luck.  Like most of the skull locations in Halo 3, it is hard to describe well without a video.  The best written description I can give is this:

1. On Tsavo Highway you'll fight some Wraiths, and then take the highway path left typically in a Warthog.
2. Listen for a guy on the radio to say "Commander, this is Oni Recon One-Eleven..."
3. Right about this time, there will be a big pipe on your left, with a ladder.  Climb the ladder and walk right along the top of the pipe.
4. There is a steep cliff wall on your left as you proceed, that come to a sudden drop off.  As soon as you reach the drop off turn left and drop down.  It's a long drop and your shields will take damage but you won't die.
5. Walk several steps forward and look to your left.  You'll see the Tough Luck skull on a nearby cliff edge that you can jump to.

A video paint 1000 words at 60 fps, so I can't compete with that - check this out for a video walkthrough: